# How to setState from a three layrered object?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, setstate

I have a three nested/layered object that I'm using setState to update the content of this object.

Payloads

```
export interface DentistPayload {
  croNumber: string;
  person: PersonPayload;
}

export interface PersonPayload {
  fullName: string;
  birthdate: string;
  cpfNumber: string;
  telephoneNumber: string;
  emailAddress: string;
  address: AddressPayload;
}

export interface AddressPayload {
  mainAddress: string;
  numberAddress: string;
  neighborHood: string;
  complementInfo: string;
  zipCode: string;
}
```

JSON

```
{
    "croNumber":"272727",
    "person": {
        "fullName": "John",
        "birthdate": "2000-02-27",
        "cpfNumber": "11408247910",
        "telephoneNumber": "47996034002",
        "emailAddress": "john@gmail.com",
        "address": {
            "mainAddress": "Rua Amoroso Costa",
            "numberAddress": "171",
            "neighborHood": "Jardim das Américas",
            "complementInfo": "Casa",
            "zipCode": "81530-150"
        }
    }
 
}
```

Right now, I'm trying to update the mainAddress property following this code, but I'm getting anywhere.

```
onChange={(e) => setFormDentist({ ...formDentist, person: { address: { ...formDentist.person.address, mainAddress: e.target.value } } })}
```

How this can be done?

Edit:

I'm receiving this error:

> `Type '{ address: { mainAddress: string; numberAddress: string; neighborHood: string; complementInfo: string; zipCode: string; }; }' is missing the following properties from type 'PersonPayload': fullName, birthdate, cpfNumber, telephoneNumber, emailAddress`

I'm using this onChange in a input HTML element to update a state like this:

```
const [formDentist, setFormDentist] = useState<DentistPayload>({} as DentistPayload)
```

Comment: Can we show a minimal reproducible example ? There's probably too little code right now to guess what the issue can be.

Comment: Post more code and errors returned, it will help us solving it.

Comment: @Axnyff added more code.

Comment: The problem is that you're not also spreading person, it should look like
`setFormDentist({ ...formDentist, person: { ...formDentist.person, address: { ...formDentist.person.address, mainAddress: e.target.value } } })`

Comment: @Axnyff it worked! Please, post your answer as a proper answer so I can accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

you are doing it wrong it is missing other person properties which you aren't spreading in your onChange function. rest of your code is good nothing wrong with that

```
onChange={(e) => setFormDentist({ 
...formDentist, 
   person: {
        ...formDentist.person, 
        address: {
          ...formDentist.person.address, 
          mainAddress: e.target.value 
        } 
   } 
 })
}
```

a better way of doing it

```
onChange={(e) => setFormDentist((prev) => ({ 
    ...prev, 
       person: {
            ...prev.person, 
            address: {
              ...prev.person.address, 
              mainAddress: e.target.value 
            } 
       } 
     }))
    }
```